# Inserting listitems in radiobuttonlist results in identical value and text attributes

Tags: asp.net, attributes, radiobuttonlist

When I assign listitems dynamically to a radiobuttonlist, the value attribute of the individual listitems is equal to the text value of that listitem.
In short, my value is not used for the attribute value.

```
Dim items As New ListItemCollection()
items.Add(New ListItem("hi there", "30"))

rblCompanyType.DataSource = items
rblCompanyType.DataBind()

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblCompanyType" Width="490" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>



<table style="width:490px;" id="CPHCenter_rblCompanyType">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" value="hi there" name="ctl00$CPHCenter$rblCompanyType" id="CPHCenter_rblCompanyType_0">
            <label for="CPHCenter_rblCompanyType_0">hi there</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you tell us what would you like to achieve, what did you try and how did you fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign the items collection like this. The correct way is:

```
  Dim items As New ListItemCollection()
     items.Add(New ListItem("hi there", "30"))


     foreach (ListItem item in items)
          rblCompanyType.Items.Add(item);
```